# Create synced realm in Library instead of Documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to set location of synced realm from default `Documents` directory that is visible in Files app on iOS to `Library` directory of the app.

I've tried to change `configuration.fileUrl` to point to `<app-directory>/Library/realm/<username>.realm` and in simulator I see that realm is created at that location but I can't get anything from it since it's empty. Every object returns `nil`. Meanwhile `Documents` directory still has synced realm data.

First I sign in with user already existing on Realm server and setup singleton realm configuration used across the app:

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: Constants.Realm.authURL) { (realmUser, error) in
    if let user = realmUser {
        RealmManager.shared.config = user.configuration(realmURL: RealmManager.syncedURL,
                                                        fullSynchronization: true,
                                                        serverValidationPolicy: ServerValidationPolicy.system,
                                                        urlPrefix: nil)

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = RealmManager.shared.config
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: RealmManager.shared.config, callback: { [weak self] (realm, error) in
            if let realm = realm {
                if let signedInUser = realm.objects(User.self).first {
                    self?.currentUser = signedInUser
                    KeychainManager.saveCredentials(email: email, password: password)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name.userDidSignIn))
                    SyncNotificationManager.shared.checkForNotificationWithDelay()
                    completion(signedInUser, nil)
                } else {
                    // Here I'm getting nil for a user if I changed default location from Documents to Library/realm/identity.realm
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In `RealmManager.shared.config` on `didSet` I do following:

```
var realmPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("realm")

var config: Realm.Configuration! {
    didSet {
        let username = SyncUser.current?.identity ?? UUID().uuidString
        config.fileURL = realmPath.appendingPathComponent("\(username).realm")
        config.encryptionKey = KeychainManager.getEncryptionKey()
        config.shouldCompactOnLaunch = { totalBytes, usedBytes in
            // totalBytes refers to the size of the file on disk in bytes (data + free space)
            // usedBytes refers to the number of bytes used by data in the file

            // Compact if the file is over 100MB in size and less than 50% 'used'
            let oneHundredMB = 100 * 1024 * 1024
            return (totalBytes > oneHundredMB) && (Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes)) < 0.5
        }
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
        do {
            realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
        } catch {
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You're trying to move an existing realm to another location but you've not included the code that does that task so we can take a look. Additionally, if you've not actually moved the data and point realm to a different location, it will create a realm but it will be empty. Can you please clarify and update the question?

Comment: @Jay I've updated question with code samples, I hope it's more clear now. It's okay to create realm files in Library folder on first sign in / sign up, no need to move existing ones if that's not possible.

Comment: That's some pretty complex code; maybe overly complex and upon initial look, it seems the config is being set, and then reset and so on. Take a look at the code in the getting started guide [Configure a local realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#configuring-a-realm) and the *setDefaultRealmForUser* function. I think you could replace all of that code with what's shown in the example (adding in Crashytics etc) and that would greatly simplify the task of using Realm at a different path. Also note that Realms should really be stored in the */Documents* directory and not elsewhere.

Comment: Also, what is `realmPath.` as it doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Note that this is synced realm and I don't want realm to be visible via iTunes and Files app. Realm path is defined as:  `var realmPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("realm")`. I've added it to code sample as well.

Comment: Doesn't this `FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory` point to the user Library directory at `~/library`? If I `print(realmPath)` it prints `file:///Users/your_username/Library/realm`. If I then use `print(config.fileURL)` within the didSet method it prints `file:///Users/your_username/Library/realm/your_username.realm`. It doesn't appear your accessing the app directory in that code at all.

Comment: If you try to use FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("realm") it will point to Library directory INSIDE the app folder where Documents folder is as well.

Comment: I have sandboxing off so my path is different. Also, the documents folder is at the same level at the Library folder, not inside. I don't think there's enough info in the question to really answer because you have some kind of RealmManager and we don't know what values it's returning. For example suppose `RealmManager.syncedURL` is pointing to the wrong place. In that case this `RealmManager.shared.config` will point to the wrong place as well, and then so will this `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above, the code keeps overwriting the vars and it's not clear why; for example this happens `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config` right after `SyncUser.logIn` but then in the didSet function, it's doing the same thing `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config`. I think if you refactor that code and simplify it, the original issue may reveal itself.

Comment: @Jay you totally miss understood question. It’s about synced ream (server realm). And at the end I found out in documentation why it doesn’t work. It’s because you can’t change where and how synced realm caches and stores data. Did asked them if there’s any workaround or plan for change, will post answer after that.

Comment: I got the question. Of course you can change where a local sync'd realm file is stored. We do it all the time. We have several Realms for each user and they are stored in different locations - one is data we want to ensure is backed up and another is constants which don't need to be backed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214533/discussion-between-najdan-tomic-and-jay).